# Cannot send messages to AgoraRTM channel

Tags: swift4.2, agora.io

I am developing the app the message "Hello" is sent when you enter the chat room by the following Swift4.2 code. And, I check whether the message was sent or not by checking the sample app of Agora-RTM-Tutorial. However, the message "Hello" was not shown on the sample app when I enter the chat room on the developing app. I confirmed to be able to send and receive messages via the sample app. So, it is thought the developing app cannot send messages. There is nothing any error messages. Could you please tell me the cause of this problem?

```
import UIKit
import AgoraRtmKit

class ChatRoomViewController: UIViewController, AgoraRtmChannelDelegate, AgoraRtmDelegate{
    private var kit: AgoraRtmKit?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        kit = AgoraRtmKit(appId: "***", delegate: self)
        var session: Void = kit!.login(byToken: nil,user: "testuser");
        var channel: AgoraRtmChannel?
        channel = kit!.createChannel(withId: "testChannel", delegate: self)
        channel!.send(AgoraRtmMessage(text: "Hello"))
    }
}
```

I withhold to write the appID and replace "***".

Comment: I have another problem.  The following sample app uses variable "user", "content" and "message" on "MessageCell.swift" but I was not able to find rows assign values to them.  Would you please tell me where assign values to them.

The sample app (Real-time Messaging SDK iOS v1.2.2) → https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/downloads

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. In the sample app, when the app receives a message, it gets a messageReceived callback, and saves the content of the message to an array, which is then displayed in a table view of MessageCells. 

Regarding the main query - are you trying to communicate between your app and the sample app? Are you sure they're using the same appID and channel? Have you implemented the AgoraRtmChannelDelegate methods?